# Can I shell out from a jq custom function

Tags: shell, jq

## Context

I have a server which has a bunch of routes which may take a json body as an input and may answer with a json response as an output, and I want to quickly test these routes and various combinations of them.

The commands I am using manually look like :

```bash
curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @- http://$HOST:$PORT/route1 | jq
```

I want to be able to compose these routes, piping them. Currently, I use a small script ./jqr which looks like :

```bash
case $1 in
    route1)
        jq 'filter_input_route1' |
        curl -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d @- http://$HOST:$PORT/route1 |
        jq
        ;;
# ...
```

And can be used like this :

```bash
./jqr route1 < share_example_a.json | jq 'some_manual_processing'
```

Which is better but far from perfect.

## Problem

Ideally, I would like to extract the curl invocation in a jq function rather than in a shell program, so as to be able to do

```bash
jq 'route1|some_manual_processing' < share_example_a.json
```

It may not look like much, but in addition to save alternating calls of jq and ./jqr,  piping and copying is a lot more powerful in jq than in bash. Say I have routes `add` and `disable` with no output and a route `list` with no input, I could do things like :

```bash
echo '{"name":"toto","enabled":true}' | jq 'route_add,route_list|.[]|select(.name=="toto")'
```

```bash
jq 'route_list|.[]|select(.name=="toto")|route_disable'
```

Where `def filter_input_route_disable : {"id":.id}`

## What I tried and looked up

Again, because piping and copying is much more convenient in jq than in bash, making a wrapper script around jq to augment its capabilities seems highly impractical and time consuming.

jq 's manual, while otherwise very thorough, is very indigent when it comes to custom functions and modules. I did manage to find some other sources to learn how to write them, but during my testings in `jq-1.6`, I didn't manage to shell out from a jq custom function.

It seems to be a popular feature request more than a decade old, approved by stedolan
https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/147
which still wasn't implemented somewhat recently
https://github.com/jqlang/jq/issues/1101
. I assume there are privilege issues involved : https://github.com/jqlang/jq/pull/1005
. Additionally, there might be issues with order of operations and (a)synchronicity, maybe jq language makes assumptions not compatible with what I want to do, and maybe it would not work well with awaiting results from a network request, I really have no clue.

One possible solution might be to write a jq function in C rather than in jq, like some built-in functions are, but I have no idea where to start.

Am I going the right way about my issue or am I having an XY problem ?

## Subsequent questions

Assuming a crude combination of curl and jq is the right way, is there anything I am missing ? Like a jq version or fork capable of shelling out ?

Assuming I didn't miss anything, is it worth attempting to write jq custom functions in C ? Like would it take more than a handful easy lines per route, and less than an hour of constant overhead, learning and setting things up ?

Comment: (1) A lot of this is broad/fuzzy/opinion-based judgment calls and not really the kind of narrow, specific question that's ideal for our format. (2) I'm not sure I understand where you're hitting the limits of shell pipes here; maybe the overview is too high-level to really sink in, or is relying on unstated details of the use case. _In a lot of cases_ I'd expect to be able to feed output from several different curl calls into input of a single jq invocation, whether via listing them on a single argv (`jq ... <(curl ...) <(curl ...) <(curl ...)`) or otherwise

Comment: ...so if I were writing code that needed to do one curl invocation to decide what inputs jq needed to be handed, I'd expect to need exactly two jq calls -- one to decide on what inputs are needed, and another to receive and process all those inputs.

Comment: (granted, dynamically generating a command line with an arbitrary number of process substitutions as arguments isn't necessarily pretty -- there's an eval-based approach and a recursive approach, maybe some more are possible if one uses dynamic file descriptor allocation introduced late in the bash 4.x series -- but while it's not _pretty_, it's possible to implement robustly even so).

Comment: I've seen people use python and the jq bindings to script out more complex scenarios. Do your calls that way?